# The STL tag uses the wrong language for syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

The [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag lists C as the language used for code highlighting ("Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-c" on the [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info)). This is the incorrect language, as it should be "lang-cpp" (C++).

While sounding minor, it creates a problem for syntax highlighting as the [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag is usually used in questions with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag. According to [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109),

> If there's more than one tag that has a highlighting language specified, or if none of the tags have one specified, it uses a default and lets highlight.js infer what's the best language to use.

this will revert to the default mode, which doesn't always correctly recognize the code as C++ code.

Can the language associated with [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) be updated to "lang-cpp" to avoid this conflict? (I'm assuming that if two tags specify the *same* language, it will be used for coloring.)

Comment: I'm pondering if another option is to have the highlighting for [tag:stl] set to `<None>` here... rather than force it to `lang-cpp`... that way it'd allow language tags to have their little `default` guessing without actually something just tagged (perhaps incorrectly and missing a language tag) `stl` forced to C++ highlighting...

Comment: @JonClements That makes sense. Almost 95% of the STL questions are also tagged C++ (the rest would either be missing the language tag or using the STL tag incorrectly).

Comment: Okay... for now then... I've set it to be `<None>` as it's an easily un-doable change (and shouldn't break anything that's not incorrectly tagged) and let's see how that works - if you have a look at a couple of posts you had in mind - are they okay now?

Comment: @JonClements Yep, that looks better.